# Issues with Springboot SwaggerUI

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, spring-boot-test

New to springboot. I am having issues with Bringing up the Swagger UI.

This is my application.properties

```
# src/main/resources/application.properties

# Datasource
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/meddb
spring.datasource.username=service_user
spring.datasource.password=${DB_PASSWORD}
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

# JPA/Hibernate properties
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect

# Logging
logging.level.root=INFO
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
logging.file.name=app.log



# Enable HTTPS
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=${KEYSTORE_PASSWORD}
server.ssl.keyStoreType=JKS
server.ssl.keyAlias=tomcat
server.port=8443
```

my **Pom.xml** looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>edu.fcc</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-med-system</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Demo Medical System</name>
    <description>A demo system for managing patient records</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
        <spring-boot-admin.version>3.1.5</spring-boot-admin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Swagger dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot-admin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest</builder>
                    </image>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And my **securityconfig** look like this

```
package xxx.xxx.demomedsystem.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authz -> authz
                        .requestMatchers("/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui.html", "/v2/api-docs", "/webjars/**")
                        .permitAll()
                        .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated())
                .requiresChannel(channel -> channel
                        .anyRequest()
                        .requiresSecure())
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable());

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

And **swaggerconfig** looks like this

```
package xxx.xxx.demomedsystem.config;

import org.springdoc.core.GroupedOpenApi;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public GroupedOpenApi publicApi() {
        return GroupedOpenApi.builder()
                .group("public")
                .pathsToMatch("/**")
                .build();
    }
}
```

My test script is as simple as

```
package xxx.xxx.demomedsystem;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
class DemoMedicalSystemApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

When I try to access SwaggerUI this is what is happenings

**In command prompt**

```
C:\Users\xxxxx>curl -k https://localhost:8443/swagger-ui/

C:\Users\xxxxx>
```

Just returns to command prompt. In Web browser (Edge, Firefox and Chrome)
when i try to go to
**https://localhost:8443/app/swagger-ui.html**

It first displays

*Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from localhost (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). Learn more
NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID*

If I continue by clicking advanced. I get

*Access to localhost was denied
You don't have authorization to view this page.
HTTP ERROR 403*

Any idea how to work around this problem. Stuck for quite some time now.

Since build was successful should at least the swagger UI come up?

By the way I am using
**mvn clean install** to build
and
**mvn spring-boot:run** to run.

As I said I am new to this. So it is very much possible I am missing something.Any help is appreciated.